# Is there a good replacement for the Dock?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, dock, window-manager, utilities

> What are the best dock replacements?
>
> It's frustrating to keep track of
>   windows in the dock unless they're
>   minimized. For instance, I often have
>   10-15 separate PDF documents open.
>   It's a mess to keep track of them on
>   the dock.

-- Harry Gindi

Comment: What do you dislike so much about the Dock? I don't really have a problem with it. Knowing what issues you have would help create better solutions.

Comment: TBH, I wouldn't use the Dock to keep track of windows. I wouldn't recommend minimizing windows, either - you just forget that you had something open. Use Application Windows (F3 on my Mac, but I think it varies) to show open windows, or use Tabs. You can right-click on the Dock to get a list of an app's windows, and there's some other useful stuff there too, like a quick way to Force Quit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[**HyperDock**](http://hyperdock.bahoom.de/) gives you window previews for each running app in the dock, which helps tremendously.

[image]

Comment: So does the Dock if you click and hold on the icon of a running app.

Comment: Yeah, but not like this. This is instantaneous and it doesn't take over your screen like the Expose view you get when holding a click on the app. HyperDock shows you the windows from all spaces, unlike Expose. Plus there are a whole slew of other useful things I haven't mentioned.

Comment: Huge fan of this app. Been a paying customer for quite some time now.  That said, as great as it is, the support is horrible.  Well, it can't be called horrible if it doesn't exist!  I tried contacting support several times over a mis-typed email address which kept me from getting my license, but the person didn't reply.  (Yes, I wrote from a different email address and yes, I included it in the text as well.) Honestly, I was so mad that after two months of trying I was going to leave, but the program is just too good, so I ended up reluctantly paying again. Love the app. Hate the support.

Answer (score 3):

A quasi-replacement worth considering is Quicksilver (download: https://qsapp.com/ and guide: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBvFUhTqKK4), used by a large number of devout users.

Though, that it depends on what you're looking to replace: access to apps, documents, tasks etc? It should work great. If you want something that looks vaguely like a dock/taskbar/GNOME panel, it won't replace that.

Comment: LaunchBar... Alfred... Google QuickSearch Box... Even Spotlight!

Comment: Quite right! I've actually had Spotlight replace QS for months…

Comment: I use Spotlight instead of QS too. Works fine.

Comment: The YouTube video requires sign in!

Comment: @Flimm This answer is 5 years old and probably no longer relevant…

Comment: Definitely no longer relevant, as the link to Blacktree.com doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Br.Bill There you go, I updated it.

Answer (score 3):

http://brawersoftware.com/products/ubar

I was impressed with this. It is the closest thing to a task bar replacement I found. Some of its behavior annoyed me so I did not purchase it at the end of the trial. You may fare diffently.

The DOCK is rather ill conceived for a variety of reasons, but programs leaving the dock when open is a huge one. Finding open windows is OSX is far more difficult than in Windows. alt-tab > cmd+tab then cmd+~. Seeing the window clearly on the task bar is also nice.

EDIT: I found this forum while looking for a replacement for ubar. I was unable to find one worth a crap. So I ended up buying Ubar, even tho it has some issues. Even with its issues it is better than the dock. The dock is a common complaint for windows users; this isnt a case of stubborn users rejecting change or a different way of doing things. This is a case of the taskbar really being the better way fulfill these functions.

Comment: Hi, I'm the developer of uBar. Send me an email with your issues and I'll see if I can resolve them. Cheers.

Comment: An issue I am having is that multiple  instances of the a program do not show up as multiple (or grouped) items on the ubar, and go to the dock. So I need to use both.

Comment: For future people wanting to try uBar - don't. It's abandoned. Bugged. Lagging. Crashing. Freezing. And developer ditched everything. But still takes money when you buy uBar :) Don't be fooled like me people

Answer (score 0):

Ubar is very nice. But I don't think it's a dock replacement. Because for me a big job of the dock is the list of icons for my commonly used apps. As far as I can tell, uBar doesn't do that...@Edward

Answer (score 0):

I'm an ActiveDock developer, the application is actively developing, version 2 is now available
https://noteifyapp.com/activedock/

Answer (score -3):

System Preferences->Dock: set "minimize windows into application icon".

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: we will see about soon enough.

Comment: How does this replace the dock?